# Parsing a json list of dictionaries in Arrow (C++)

Tags: c++, json, apache-arrow

I have the following json file:

```json
{"b": [{"x": 1}, {"x": 2}, {"x": 3}]}
```

and want to parse the values of the dictionaries within the list (ideally as an array of integers) in C++ using Arrow 8.0.0.

My current code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/filesystem/api.h>
#include <arrow/json/api.h>
#include <arrow/memory_pool.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  // Copied from https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/json.html#basic-usage
  arrow::Status st;
  arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();
  auto fs =
      arrow::fs::FileSystemFromUri("file:///path/to/arrow_json")
          .ValueOrDie();
  auto file = fs->OpenInputFile("/path/to/arrow_json/test.json")
                  .ValueOrDie();

  auto read_options = arrow::json::ReadOptions::Defaults();
  auto parse_options = arrow::json::ParseOptions::Defaults();

  auto reader =
      arrow::json::TableReader::Make(pool, file, read_options, parse_options)
          .ValueOrDie();

  auto table = reader->Read().ValueOrDie();

  auto b = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::StructArray>(
      table->GetColumnByName("b")->chunk(0));

  std::cout << "b: " << b->ToString() << "\n";
  /*
  b->ToString shows:
b: [
  -- is_valid: all not null
  -- child 0 type: int64
    [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
]
  */

  auto x = b->GetFieldByName("x");  // this segfaults
  if (x) {
    auto val = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::Int64Array>(x);
    if (val) {
      std::cout << "val\n";
      std::cout << "val: " << val->ToString() << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Why does the code segfault when trying to access "x" and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to retrieve the values. But I hope someone will provide a cleaner way to do this.

EDIT: Thank you @0x26res for your suggestions! I updated the code accordingly.

```cpp
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/filesystem/api.h>
#include <arrow/json/api.h>
#include <arrow/memory_pool.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  // Copied from https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/json.html#basic-usage
  arrow::Status st;
  arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();
  auto fs =
      arrow::fs::FileSystemFromUri("file:///path/to/arrow_json").ValueOrDie();
  auto file = fs->OpenInputFile("/path/to/arrow_json/test.json").ValueOrDie();

  auto read_options = arrow::json::ReadOptions::Defaults();
  auto parse_options = arrow::json::ParseOptions::Defaults();

  auto reader =
      arrow::json::TableReader::Make(pool, file, read_options, parse_options)
          .ValueOrDie();

  auto table = reader->Read().ValueOrDie();
  std::cout << "table schema: " << table->schema()->ToString() << "\n";
  /*
    This shows: table schema: b: list<item: struct<x: int64>>
  */

  auto vec_of_chunks = table->GetColumnByName("b")->chunks();

  for (const auto& chunk : vec_of_chunks) {
    auto b_list = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::ListArray>(chunk);

    auto b_struct = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::StructArray>(
        b_list->Flatten().ValueOrDie());

    auto x_arr = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::Int64Array>(
        b_struct->GetFieldByName("x"));

    for (int i = 0; i < x_arr->length(); i++) {
      auto x = x_arr->Value(i);
      std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's not technically correct. If you print `table->schema()` you'll notice that your data is of type `b: list<item: struct<x: int64>>`. So `b` should be a `ListArray` and `b_flat` a `StructArray`. Also using a `StructScalar` is somewhat inefficient. You can get around it by doing `auto x_flat = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::Int64Array>(b_flat->GetFieldByName("x"));`. Lastly don't forget you need to do this for each chunks in `table->GetColumnByName("b")`

Comment: A follow up question: can it be adapted to read from json lines?
`
{"a.name":"Australia"}
{"a.name":"Austria"}
{"a.name":"Azerbaijan"}
`